# how to make same custom taxonomy to have different posts of a different post type in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am using a custom type plugin to make a custom post type "Products" with custom taxonomy "Product Categories" with some categories like "pvc hose" etc.

The problem is that i wanted to make another custom post type "Brands" with the same custom taxonomy "Product Categories" with same categories like "pvc hose" etc.

I have made this but the problem is that when i am making posts in the second custom post type "Brands" with category name "pvc hose", that post is also getting stored in the first custom post type "Products" and getting displayed in a page along with the posts of the custom post type "Products". I dnt want like this, this should be separate from the other.

Can anyone say a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

In your function.php file use the following code

```
    add_action('admin_init','register_my_tax');
    function register_my_tax(){
        register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'your-custom-taxonomy-name', 'your-post-type' );
    }
```

[register_taxonomy_for_object_type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type)

Comment: i have written this code in functions.php. but it is not showing.

Comment: I have written it like this : register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'product', 'brand' ); but not working.

Comment: is your taxonomy product or product_category?? please make sure you are using proper taxonomy name.
Is your custom post type 'brand' in which you want to have product category?

Comment: register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'product-category', 'brand' ); its like this. but it is not working

Comment: create a sample post of your post type brand and take a look at your database table wp_post and search for post_type value of your newly created post and make sure the post type is brand not something like cpt_brand.

Comment: Please take a look at updated code, i've added the hook to call that function. if your taxonomy name and post type is correct then i surely will work.